# How to use travis-ci's .travis.yml to provide environment parameters for Node.js Application?

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, travis-ci

I use travis-ci to test my node.js application. Because the application need users login with Access Key and Secret Key to test, I need to specify these two keys in travis-ci's .travis.yml file. So How can i do this? And how to get these environment parameters in Node?

Like these two parameters: https://github.com/ikbear/nodejs-sdk/blob/feature/copy_and_move_file/test/rs.test.js#L22

I want to specify them in .travis.yml like this:

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - 0.8
  - 0.6
  - 0.4
env:
  - QINIU_ACCESS_KEY = '2FRuiVGEsA511NS9pNd2uvuSB3k5ozXE_DHCH8Ov' QINIU_SECRET_KEY = 'CIRtcmymB3VeIfXebFvYxmMmH9u2oLKW6rffVvoK'
```

So how can i get QINIU_ACCESS_KEY and QINIU_SECRET_KEY from my this test file? https://github.com/ikbear/nodejs-sdk/blob/feature/copy_and_move_file/test/rs.test.js

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Update**: Travis now supports [defining variables directly in build respositories](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/#Defining-Variables-in-Repository-Settings) via their web user interface.  So, unless you have a need to [generate local encrypted variables manually for your **.travis.yml** file](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/#Defining-encrypted-variables-in-.travis.yml) (as per original answer below), this seems like the easiest way to get an environment variable working with Travis CI.

---

I'm not sure of specifics regarding Node.js, but if you want to use `QINIU_ACCESS_KEY` and `QINIU_SECRET_KEY` in your **.travis.yml** without them being plain text, make them [secure environment variables](http://about.travis-ci.org/docs/user/build-configuration/#Secure-environment-variables):

Step 0:  Install the travis gem ([Install Rubygems](http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/3) if you haven't got it already; not sure if there's another way to get the `travis` command or another way to perform Step 1 below):

```
$ gem install travis
```

Step 1: Encrypt the values, taking note of the result:

```
$ travis encrypt QINIU_ACCESS_KEY=2FRuiVGEsA511NS9pNd2uvuSB3k5ozXE_DHCH8Ov
$ travis encrypt QINIU_SECRET_KEY=CIRtcmymB3VeIfXebFvYxmMmH9u2oLKW6rffVvoK
```

Step 2: Add the values to your **.travis.yml** file:

```
env:
  global: 
    - secure: {{ENCRYPTED_QINIU_ACCESS_KEY}}
    - secure: {{ENCRYPTED_QINIU_SECRET_KEY}}
```

(Multiple keys called `secure` are no problem)

Next time your app goes through Travis, you should see on the Config line:

> Env: QINIU_ACCESS_KEY=[secure] QINIU_SECRET_KEY=[secure]

More StackOverflow Q&As that may be of assistance (it's in a Ruby on Rails context, but they deal with this issue) are here:

- [How to deploy an rails app on heroku from travis-ci?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10235026/567863)
- [Using secret api keys on travis-ci](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9338428/567863)

Comment: Great and complete answer!  If you need to set many secure environment variables, it my be easier to do in the `.travis.yml` file.  I have a lot of env vars in a `.env` file and built a ruby script to iterate over them and run the travis command over it.  A bit easier than copy pasting them in travis web interface.

Answer (score 0):

Read here (Using Environment Variables with Travis-CI!) --> https://github.com/dwyl/learn-environment-variables#using-environment-variables-with-travis-ci-

Also, to learn more about Travis, read here (Learn Travis) --> https://github.com/dwyl/learn-travis