# Add credentials to allow Travis-CI to use a private Nexus repository

Tags: sbt, nexus, travis-ci

I'm using Travis for continuous integration.  However, my projects depend on a private Nexus repository.  I would rather not check in sbt credentials into our repository.  Travis does support [encryption keys](http://about.travis-ci.org/docs/user/encryption-keys/) but they only affect environment variables.

How can I get Travis to authenticate against Nexus?  `sbt` does not seem to support credentials from an environment variable.

https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/0.13/launch/src/main/scala/xsbt/boot/Update.scala#L56

There looks like there is support to specify a credentials file from an environment variable, or to specify credentials as system properties.  Unfortunately, this didn't seem to work with `0.13`.

```
sbt -Dsbt.boot.realm="Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager" -Dsbt.boot.host="www.there.com" -Dsbt.boot.user="deployment" -Dsbt.boot.password="password" aether-deploy
```

Comment: Are you sure that Travis CI is using the sbt 0.13 launcher? Remember, the launcher version does not necessarily correspond to the version of sbt that is actually launched. Theoretically, old launchers can launch new sbt versions, and vice-versa (although this does not always work).

Comment: You can detect the launcher version by running `--version` when launching.

Comment: @robin-green, no I'm not sure.  However, I am sure I'm using 0.13 on my machine and it's not working there either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set global variables in your .travis.yml as defined here: 
http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/build-configuration/#Set-environment-variables

Those global vars can be encrypted for travis using the travis gem. Explained e.g. here:
[How to use travis-ci's .travis.yml to provide environment parameters for Node.js Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14471666/how-to-use-travis-cis-travis-yml-to-provide-environment-parameters-for-node-js)

Comment: We tried this and it was OK. We ended up checking in raw credentials and feeling bad about it.

Answer (score 4):

You want to use Travis secure environment variables as documented. Assuming your environment variables are `NEXUS_USER` and `NEXUS_PASS`, the command line needs to be:

```
sbt 'set credentials += Credentials("Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager", "www.there.com", System.getenv("NEXUS_USER"), System.getenv("NEXUS_PASS"))' aether-deploy
```

You could also safely have that line in your `build.sbt`, if you wanted to make that a standard practice for your builds.

The [Jackson Scala Module](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-scala) uses this for deploying Travis builds to the Sonatype OSS repository. You can our `.travis.yml` to see how it's set up.