# What should be removed from public source control in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, security

I've been searching the web, and I can't find any good/recent examples of what to exclude from a new public rails app.  I'm looking to open source my app on GitHub and am wondering what types of data should be removed from source control.

From what I can tell, there should be a `config/config.yml` file that has private information.  I've been looking through the other files, and it looks like `config/database.yml`, `config/intializers/secret_token.rb` and `config/initializers/session_store.rb` should also be excluded?

Is it best practice to exclude all of these files separately?  Or is there a way to have the info all defined in `config/config.yml` and be called in each of those files?  Additionally, what files and data should be kept private and hidden?  Is that all of them?

I'm just wondering what approach I should take and what is the best practice.  Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I've been looking into this recently as well; I wanted to keep sensitive information hidden throughout the process of pushing open source code to Github, then automatically pushed to [Travis CI](https://travis-ci.org/) for testing, then from Travis being automatically deployed to [Heroku](http://www.heroku.com/).  Here are all the details of what I've found so far looking at various StackOverflow Q&As, blogs etc, which will hopefully serve as a reference for you, even if only for config inside the Rails app (omit any `{{ ... }}` you see)

*Disclaimer: I'm by no means an expert here, so please keep in mind there are likely better ways to do this than what I'm trying.  I'd love to be able to learn some new tricks in this Q&A thread.*

---

### Inside the Rails App

I currently use the [Figaro gem](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro) to hide sensitive information in `ENV` environment variables.  In my (`.gitignore`d) **config/application.yml**, I keep the following information:

```
# App keys
SECRET_TOKEN: # your rake secret generated token

development:
  DB_NAME: # your dev db name here
  DB_USER: # your dev db username here
  DB_PASSWORD: # your dev db password here

test:
  DB_NAME: # your test db name here
  DB_USER: # your test db username here
  DB_PASSWORD: # your test db password here

production:
  DB_NAME: # your prod db name here
  DB_USER: # your prod db username here
  DB_PASSWORD: # your prod db password here

# Third Party keys that you will reference in their relevant files
THIRD_PARTY_API_OR_LICENSE_KEY: # list of whatever api/license keys you use
```

(`DB_NAME`, `DB_USER`, and `DB_PASSWORD` will be used dynamically depending on what environment your app is running in).

An empty version of the above file (**config/application.example.yml**) gets pushed to Github with some instructions on how to fill it in.

The files that are pushed to Github and reference these variables look like this:

**config/database.yml**
(Postgresql is used here, but you should be able to change the settings for whatever database you use)

```
postgresql: &postgresql
  adapter: postgresql
  database: <%= ENV['DB_NAME'] %>
  username: <%= ENV['DB_USER'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['DB_PASSWORD'] %>
  min_messages: ERROR

defaults: &defaults
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  host: localhost
  <<: *<%= ENV['DB'] || "postgresql" %>

development:
  <<: *defaults

test:
  <<: *defaults

production:
  <<: *defaults
```

**config/initializers/secret_token.rb**

```
if Rails.env.production? && ENV['SECRET_TOKEN'].blank?
  raise 'SECRET_TOKEN environment variable must be set!'
end

YourApp::Application.config.secret_token = 
  ENV['SECRET_TOKEN'] || {{WHATEVER_SECRET_TOKEN_RAILS_GENERATED_BY_DEFAULT}}
```

(Plus, whatever files would be referencing `THIRD_PARTY_API_OR_LICENSE_KEY`-type keys.)

### Testing on Travis CI

Create encrypted travis variables using the [Travis gem](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis).  The Heroku API key and Heroku Git URL are needed if you deploy direct to Heroku from a Travis worker (see [this StackOverflow Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10235026/567863) for details), otherwise you can omit them if you just use it for testing:

```
$ gem install travis
$ travis encrypt your_username/your_repo HEROKU_API_KEY={{YOUR_HEROKU_API_KEY}}
$ travis encrypt HEROKU_GIT_URL={{YOUR_HEROKU_GIT_URL}} # eg git@heroku.com:your_app.git
$ travis encrypt DB_NAME={{YOUR_DB_NAME_UNDER_TEST}} # eg your_app_test
$ travis encrypt DB_USER={{YOUR_DB_USER_UNDER_TEST}}
$ travis encrypt DB_PASSWORD={{YOUR_DB_PASSWORD_UNDER_TEST}}
```

(Plus, encrypt any other keys you may need during testing, if any...)

Then add them to **.travis.yml**
(once again Postgresql-focused, but you should be able to change the settings for whatever database you use)

```
env:
  global:
    - secure: {{YOUR_ENCRYPTED_HEROKU_API_KEY}}
    - secure: {{YOUR_ENCRYPTED_HEROKU_GIT_URL}}
    - secure: {{YOUR_ENCRYPTED_DB_NAME}}
    - secure: {{YOUR_ENCRYPTED_DB_USER}}
    - secure: {{YOUR_ENCRYPTED_DB_PASSWORD}}
  matrix:
    - DB: postgresql
before_script:
  - psql -c "create database $DB_NAME;" -U $DB_USER
  - RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rake db:migrate
script:
  - bundle exec rspec spec/
after_success:
  - gem install heroku
  - git remote add heroku $HEROKU_GIT_URL
  # ... see link above for the rest of the config content
```

Multiple variables marked with the same name of `secure` are fine; they'll show up in the config as `HEROKU_API_KEY=[secure] HEROKU_GIT_URL=[secure]` etc.

### Deployment to Heroku

Use the Figaro's Heroku rake task to automatically set the environment variables that Heroku needs to see in production:

```
$ rake figaro:heroku
```

Or, set them manually:

```
$ heroku config:set SECRET_TOKEN={{YOUR_SECRET_TOKEN}}
$ heroku config:set DB_NAME={{YOUR_DB_NAME_UNDER_PRODUCTION}} # eg your_app_production
$ heroku config:set DB_USER={{YOUR_DB_USER_UNDER_PRODUCTION}}
$ heroku config:set DB_PASSWORD={{YOUR_DB_PASSWORD_UNDER_PRODUCTION}}
$ heroku config:set THIRD_PARTY_API_OR_LICENSE_KEY={{YOUR_THIRD_PARTY_API_OR_LICENSE_KEY}}
```

Then, attempt a deployment.

---

That's all I have for now.  Not sure at the moment if I should be hiding more info or if I'm not hiding it well enough, but it's a work in progress.

Comment: Thanks for such a comprehensive solution!

Comment: Glad that it was some reference to you.  I'm hoping to update this answer as more/better info comes to light.  @joelparkerhenderson, I like the `rake:setup` idea as well.  Either that, or perhaps include the logic in a [Rails Application Template](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/rails_application_templates.html) so that all this happens whenever I generate a new app.  Something for the TODO list...

Comment: Oh, I don't know if you knew this, but I was looking at the Figaro gem and it looks like it provides a way to automatically do the heroku configuration through `rake figaro:heroku`.

Comment: I totally missed that, even though it's staring at me in the face on the README page.  Nice, thank you for following up on this!  Since it seems you can also do Rails-environment-specific configuration, I'll try and see if I can switch out the DB_NAME_{{ENV}} variables for just one DB_NAME that will change dynamically depending on the environment it runs in.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up @RyanE. I've updated my answer to reflect what I hope is cleaner config.

Answer (score 4):

You'll get different opinions. IMHO, it's best-practice to include these files, but omit the secret content from them. Document what you're doing so developers who are new to your project know what they need to fill in.

Phusion has a good blog post about how to handle the Rails session secret, and the tradeoffs you can make to include or exclude information:

http://blog.phusion.nl/2013/01/04/securing-the-rails-session-secret/#.URYPXekTMak

My favorite way to document these is using a "rake setup" task. You can have the task print what the developer needs to do-- in other words, you don't need to automate it all (though that's nice if you're able to do it).

If you want to get fancy, have your files read the secret settings from a shared/ directory, which also enables deployment symlinking. This is described in the Phusion blog too. This is how I build apps that need to be deployed frequently.

Comment: I like the idea of the rake setup.  Thank you!