# Making ENV variables accessible in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, environment-variables

When storing sensitive credentials I normally create a yml file and load it like so in my development.rb

```
APP_CONFIG = YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root}/config/config.yml")[Rails.env]
```

I can then access like so

```
APP_CONFIG["google_secret"]
```

Problem is Heroku doesn't like this so i need to set ENV variables locally to make integration easier. so i have created a env.rb file like so

```
ENV['google_key'] = 'xxx'
ENV['google_secret'] = 'xxx'
ENV['application_key'] = 'xxx'
```

and to accesss it i thought i could use

```
x = ENV['application_key']
```

But its not finding the variable, how do I load them in the development environment?

Thanks

Comment: Please make sure that you have put the `env.rb` file in `initializers` folder.

Comment: i put my env.rb file in the config folder, is this not correct?

Comment: No. You should put env.rb file in `initializers` folder.

Comment: then i guess add that to the gitignore file aswell?

Comment: It's upto your requirements. If you don't want to push the file to heroku then you should add it to `.gitignore` file.

Comment: works great, put as answer if you like and i will accept, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should put the `env.rb` file in `initializers` folder. You can add `env.rb` file to `.gitignore` file if you don't want to push it to heroku.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using [Figaro](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro) to do this?  Figaro was [inspired by Heroku's secret key application configuration](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro#how-does-it-work-with-heroku), so it's really easy to make secret `ENV` variables in development accessible in Heroku production environments.

I wrote up an answer on [this StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14785257/567863) about hiding secret info in Rails (using Figaro) that can hopefully serve of some reference to you as well.