# Ruby on Rails 3.2.13 - Brakeman - Session secret should not be included in version control

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, brakeman

I have installed the latest version of the Brakeman gem to help me with Rails application security.

I have several Rails applications that I have on two servers, one for development and the other for production.  When I ran the Brakeman reports on my applications, most of them flagged config/initializers/secret_token.rb with the following high security vulnerability.

```
Session secret should not be included in version control near line 7
```

This is the first time I have seen this error since I ran an older version of Brakeman months ago.

From what I have researched so far Rails automatically generated the secret token when **rails new appname** is executed.  I was not aware of it until now.  Apparently Rails does not protect this file where if I decided to move any of my applications to Github the information would be available to anyone at Github accessing the application.  At this time I am not uploading to GitHub but I want information on how to move the secure_token from config/initializers/secret_token.rb in order to close the security hole in my applications.

One blog post I read suggested that I inject the secret token into an ENV variable.  Will moving the statement from config/initializers/secret_token.rb to config/environment.rb solve the problem?  If so I will add this task to my list of tasks in Rails development.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That particular message in Brakeman was silenced for me when I put secret information into `ENV` variables, as you mentioned.  Personally, I like to use the [Figaro](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro) gem for this, but I think [dotenv](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv) is popular as well.

Some other resources that may be of interest to you regarding this are:

- Code Climate blog entry: [Rails Insecure Defaults](http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2013/03/27/rails-insecure-defaults/) blog entry on Code Climate
- StackOverflow thread: [What should be removed from public source control in Ruby on Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14785257/567863)

Comment: The suggestion I mentioned about the ENV variable came from the Code Climate blog post.  I read it before posting my question.  I was not sure how to make it the ENV variable when I posted my question.  However when I took a look at environment.rb I saw the statement formats were the same.  So I moved the statement from secret_token there.  The message disappeared.  I have the Code Climate blog post in my Bookmarks.  I will check out Figaro which I saw in previous searches.  I will also look at dotenv also.

Comment: If environment.rb is stored in your source control, then it's no more safe than secret_token.rb.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how moving the session secret to a different file would make a difference. Essentially, the secret token should be treated just like a password.

[This blog post from Phusion](http://blog.phusion.nl/2013/01/04/securing-the-rails-session-secret/) explores a few different options for providing the session key at deploy time.

Comment: I read this post before asking my question.  They suggested option 2 along with patching Rails.  Several of the options assume that you are using Capistrano.  I'm not using it.  I am still learning things about Rails, especially regarding security.  Unfortunately the blog post has a lot of information that I am not familiar with.

Comment: The other file (e.g. `.env`) can be gitignored, keeping it out of version control. It can then be managed as appropriate for each platform, with developers manually editing the ignored file with a development secret, and DevOps managing it however appropriate on their server stack.