# Add secret environment variable to Travis CI

Tags: travis-ci

I'm currently trying to add a secret environment variable to Travis-CI. [In the docs](http://about.travis-ci.org/docs/user/build-configuration/) ("Secure environment variables") I found the following line to do this:

```
gem install travis
travis encrypt -r travis-ci/travis-core MY_SECRET_ENV=super_secret
```

If I understood this correctly I must replace `travis-ci/travis-core` with the name of my own repository, because the encryption should only be valid for my repository. Therefore, there must be a public key in the repository. Is there a special `travis` command to add this key? How does this exactly work? Or is this just my ssh public key?

When I run the following command:

```
travis encrypt -r my_username/my_repo MY_SECRET_ENV=super_secret
```

I get the following error:

```
There was an error while fetching public key, please check if you entered correct slug
```

Comment: Just found [this pull request on travis-cli](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-cli/pull/2), looks like this is a known issue and will be fixed soon.

Comment: `travis encrypt` now wants -r in front of the repository name. (and currently it does not work for me)

Comment: Thx, I updated the question. I just updated the gem (now using Version 1.1.3) and it works like a charm. See also [my answer to another question on the same topic](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12778315/549755).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a known issue. It already has a [pull request on GitHub](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-cli/pull/2) to fix it.
The problem is the request to get the public key of a repository does not work, because they changed the API to SSL. If you don't want to wait for the pull request to be merged, you can simply [change the source to use https instead of http](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-cli/pull/2/files).

Comment: I skipped verification of the SSL certificate for the patch otherwise it doesn't work for me

Comment: How can i disable ssl verification (I am not a ruby developer only a ruby user for this special case)?

Comment: Have you tried the newest version of the travis gem? It should work now :)