# Error fetching public key while encrypting environment variable for Travis CI

Tags: travis-ci

I'm using `travis (0.0.6)` and I get the same error as described in [Add secret environment variable to Travis CI](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12724139/341929):

> [bdu-padrino (master)]$ travis encrypt mariusbutuc/bdu-padrino MY_SECRET_ENV=super_secret
>
> About to encrypt 'MY_SECRET_ENV=super_secret' for 'mariusbutuc/bdu-padrino'
>
> There was an error while fetching public key, please check if you entered correct slug

even after [editing `lib/travis/cli/secure_key.rb`](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-cli/pull/2) to

- use either **https** or http URL to retrieve the public key,
- either skip the **SSL certificate verification** or not.

What else can I check to ensure encrypting works?

---

Also in the browser, [travis-ci.org/mariusbutuc/bdu-padrino.json](https://travis-ci.org/mariusbutuc/bdu-padrino.json) shows *Loading* forever...

What's expected to be rendered here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Version `0.0.6`—or any version prior to `0.0.10`—fails because [the endpoint for keys has been changed](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-cli/commit/0cea3baf8d754cd8c7723c5b17143655cb949612).

To fix it, simply update `lib/travis/cli/secure_key.rb` to [the one in version `0.0.10`](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-cli/blob/0cea3baf8d754cd8c7723c5b17143655cb949612/lib/travis/cli/secure_key.rb),
or update the gem.