# Travis-ci decryption of encrypted files

Tags: continuous-integration, travis-ci

I encrypted my .env file, and I now have a `.env.enc` file. How does my team decrypt this?
I got this response when I encrypted the file, and it is stored in my .travis.yml file

```
openssl aes-256-cbc -K $encrypted_cf94abc85bdc_key -iv $encrypted_cf94abc85bdc_iv -in .env.enc -out .env -d
```

I tried that on the terminal and this I just get:

```
iv undefined
```

I tried decrypting with the travis-cli:

```
travis encrypt-file .env.enc .env -d
```

I just get this:

```
key must be 64 characters long and a valid hex number
```

I tried it with the key and iv

```
travis encrypt-file .env.enc .env -d -K $encrypted_cf94abc85bdc_key -iv $encrypted_cf94abc85bdc_iv
```

I checked if the travis env variables exist, and they do:

```
encrypted_cf94abc85bdc_key=[secure]
encrypted_cf94abc85bdc_iv=[secure]
```

Comment: Presumably the file was encrypted with a key, but I see no indication of a key in that command. Don't know how Travis does things, though.

Comment: Even when I do this:
`travis encrypt-file .env.enc .env -d -K $encrypted_cf94abc85bdc_key -iv $encrypted_cf94abc85bdc_iv`
I still get the same response.

Comment: [The documentation](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis.rb/blob/master/README.md#encrypt-file) says you must specify the `key` and `iv` parameters when decrypting, but they are randomly generated when encrypting. If you didn't save them when you encrypted it, I'm guessing that .env is lost now.

Comment: Hmm. You should probably update your question to reflect this, and verify that the key you are passing is a 64-bit hex string.

Comment: You decrypt with key and iv, which are stored in repo-wide env vars on Travis

Answer (score 0):

Your file is probably decrypted somewhere during the build on Travis. It might be easiest to add a `deploy` step to the build, so the `.env` file is uploaded to a place where you can download it yourself.

For details on how to deploy files, check [this link](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment) or this [one specifically for github](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/releases/)

Here's a short sample of what I did ;)

in `.travis.yml`

```
before_install:
  // Somewhere your files are being decrypted 
  openssl aes-256-cbc -K $encrypted_cf94abc85bdc_key -iv $encrypted_cf94abc85bdc_iv -in .env.enc -out .env -d

// Add a deploy step, which allows you which files to upload
deploy:
  file: 
  - .env  /* add the file here, so it will be pushed to github */
  api_key: $apikey
  on:
    repo: <your github repo>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the output of `travis encrypt-file` !

Especially the first line:

```
encrypting <filename> for <repository name>
[..]
```

You need to be in the correct repo (and use `--com` if needed) to be sure that Travis will find the generated values it later needs.